# Why aren't my delays working?

Tags: jquery, delay

So I am working on a staged animation of a few elements. On each, I want there to be a timed delay before the next element animates. I think I have put in the code right, but none of the delays are working. Instead all the animations just happen at once. Can somebody explain what I am missing?

Thanks!

```
$(function() {
   $( "a.engine" ).click(function() {
      $( "img.bg" ).removeClass( "intro_effects");
      $(".fadein").delay(1000).css("visibility", "visible");
      $( "div.menu_container" ).delay(1300).removeClass( "hide");
      $( "div.main_content" ).delay(1600).removeClass( "hide");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because operations like removeClass()/css() does not use queue based execution which is the basis for delay so try

```
$(function () {
    $("a.engine").click(function () {
        $("img.bg").removeClass("intro_effects");
        $(".fadein").delay(1000).queue(function () {
            $(this).css("visibility", "visible")
        });
        $("div.menu_container").delay(1300).queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hide");
        });
        $("div.main_content").delay(1600).queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hide");
        });

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zbBN5/)

Comment: Interesting! I was under the impression that jQuery ran in order everytime, so I had assumed that it would read and respect the delays. Very good info to know! Hopefully this part will be covered in my jQuery lessons soon, cause that caused me to lose hair. 

thanks very much, thats perfect. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

[delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) works with animations like method but not with normal methods, as normal method doesn't uses queue

You can use [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) like

```
$(function() {
    $( "a.engine" ).click(function() {
        $( "img.bg" ).removeClass( "intro_effects");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".fadein").css("visibility", "visible");
        },1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $( "div.menu_container" ).removeClass( "hide");
        },1300);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $( "div.main_content" ).removeClass( "hide");
        },1600);
   });
});
```